# Exception : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute on form Close in setup project

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-deployment

I created a setup project of window form application built in C# 4.0. I tested the setup in my test PC which have Vs 2010 Ultimate installed in it and its working fine in it.

I later on to test the application I installed it another machine which does not have VS in it. Every time I try to close the form, it ends up with this exception. The exception is  occurring in some forms not in all. I have checked the code and and there is no difference in it(this.close()).

While building the setup I am using 
.Net Framework 4 Client Profile as Target Framework.
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs is added in setup.
My not using tab strip nor trying to close multiple form.

This is the complete error
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click quit, the application will close rimmediately.

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeCollection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at ezyBizManager.Masters.frmUsers.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ezyBizManager
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft/COE/ezyBizManager.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.20911.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------************** JIT Debugging **************
```

To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

[Edited:]
I am using image to close the form.

```
private void imgClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Form.Closing or Form.Closed method you can show here? Just the bare exception is not very useful.

Comment: That exception is usually thrown when you remove items from a collection inside a foreach loop, e.g. `foreach(var x in collection) { collection.Remove(x); }`. Does maybe the Shape's Dispose method do anything like that?

Comment: I am bit confuse now. I am not able to understand why is the same code working fine in another forms. Is there anything i should include in my setup project. Or is there any update I can run. I have already installed VS Framework 4.0

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a bug in the `Dispose()` method of `ShapeCollection`. If I look at this method using for example .NET Reflector, with Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=9.0.0.0, it says this:

```
    foreach (Shape shape in this.m_Shapes)
    {
        shape.Dispose();
    }
```

And if I look at this method using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0, it says this:

```
    for (int i = this.m_Shapes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        this.m_Shapes[i].Dispose();
    }
```

Clearly, the implementation has evolved between versions. The latter one doesn't rely on an Enumerator object and therefore cannot fail with the error you show.

What's strange though is your stackframe seems to imply you're running off version 10, which shouldn't use the enumerator?? Maybe you need a VS 2010 update? Or you can also check at the Dispose implementation on the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs you're using.

**EDIT**: after some digging, your application indeed runs on an old version of the VB Powerpacks. Upgrade to VS2010, SP1 or copy the DLL from a good installation. For this specific Dispose bug, you need at least 10.0.30319.1.

Comment: His version number is wrong, 10.0.20911.1 must have been a beta.  The RTM version is 11.0.50727.1 and has the correct Dispose implementation.

Comment: Actually, I've checked VS2010 RTM setup and the version is 10.0.30319.1 (and the Dispose bug is fixed in this version). I suppose 11.0.50727.1 is brought by VS2010 SP1 (or later fix or VS2012?). The 10.0.20911.1 comes from an earlier version that is indeed the latest one that can be downloaded individually (from this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=145727), and is referenced in a lot of threads (MSDN forums to say the least), hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same pblm with, especially with **LineShape**, after headache with installing and searching for right **PowerPacks** package, I replaced it with RichTextBox  by adjusting backcolor to balck and the size, it seems weird but it's quite better for me than spending my time with this bug !! (0_o)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I've been so confused as to what was causing the issue and have been stepping through debugging line by line for a day or so. After Google searching and typing in the right description, it turns out the issue is with line shapes on a form - and likely other shapes. See the links here, hope it saves somebody else some time... you have to read down through the comments, by like the above post it's with line shapes.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb89a159-c989-470f-b74f-df3f61b9dedd/systeminvalidoperationexception-when-closing-a-form?forum=vbpowerpacks

http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/520076-VB-2010-Error-PowerPacks-Line-Shape-Dispose/

Comment: You should precise what did help you, not just link to it

Comment: may the link contain the answer to the question, you should include essential information in the answer to avoid broken link issue

Comment: I had the same problem, but only on some installations. First I spotted the offending form by looking at the stack trace. Then I went to its Designer.vb file, and surrounded the MyBase.Dispose call with a Try/Catch, in order to prevent exceptions from that call to go unmanaged. I am aware it is not an orthodox solution, but more a workaround, but it works. The possible flaw with this technique is that the Designer.vb file is a generated one, so the code change may get overwritten, but it seems that even if I change the form design, that portion of code remains unchanged.