# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" When form closes

Tags: c#, .net, manifest

I've seen a few questions regarding the `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` error, but none of them fit my symptoms, and none of the solutions will fix my problem. Whats happening is when I close my form, at any point during runtime, a little messagebox pops up with that error. It doesn't really affect anything, but obviously I don't want an error popping up every time I close my form. Any clue what's causing this?

I edited my manifest recently, so that could be the cause, I'm not too sure. I'll post it anyways. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security> 
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. 
      Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"

      supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8.1, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!-- <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->

</asmv1:assembly>
```

Here is where the error occurs:

```
partial class MainMenu
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        }
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer shapeContainer1;
        private Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape rectangleShape1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem quitToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem profileToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem logInToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem logOutToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem createProfileToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button6;
    }
}
```

Exception stuff:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeCollection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at POS_System.InventoryMenu.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in c:\Users\user\Desktop\Co-op\Co-op\C#\POS System\POS System\POS System\InventoryMenu.Designer.cs:line 20
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Point Of Sales
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Co-op/Co-op/C%23/POS%20System/POS%20System/POS%20System/bin/Debug/Point%20Of%20Sales.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.20911.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50938.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with your manifest, you may want to post a stacktrace and some relevant code related to the error.

Comment: Perhaps you're modifying a collection on destruction and a loop elsewhere is trying to use it?

Comment: Whoops ill edit it now

Comment: Are you using a Dictionary, List or other IEnumerable in your code file?

Comment: I am using quite a few lists. Is there a way to find which one is causing this error?

Comment: What base class is "base" referring to in this case? If you are certain the error is coming from base.Dispose(disposing), that seems like a reasonable place to start. It may be helpful if you are able to post code from the base.Dispose method.

Comment: When I make a breakpoint, or break on the error, it won't let me see what base is. Where would I find the base.Dispose method? This is system generated code, I didn't write it

Comment: @Nathan you're probably looking for a list that you are using in a timer.  The cause of this error is that the list is modified (or disposed) while you're trying to enumerate it (in a foreach loop).

Comment: I am using 0 foreach loops in my program, and I don't believe I'm using a timer either. Anything else that could cause this?

Comment: Hmm...Maybe LINQ statements could cause this...Although I thought only a foreach could throw that error.  Other than timers though you could have an event that is firing.

Comment: I'm pretty new to C#, and I don't know what LINQ is, so I'm doubting it's that :p Is there any way I can trace the error to see whats throwing it?

Comment: Update: It's not only my main menu closing that causes this, they all throw the error now in their respective designer class on the same line.

Comment: When the unhandled exception pops up there is a field called InnerException, does anything show there?

Comment: This is everything that appears in the window:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Oh nevermind, when I build and run that I get the exception stuff. I'll edit my post with it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40394/discussion-between-mikeh-and-nathan)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute on form Close in setup project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788919/exception-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-on-fo)